# Bit manipulation insertion

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

```
class UpdateBits 
{
    // Function to updateBits M insert to N.
    static int updateBits(int n, int m, int i, int j)
    {
        /* Create a mask to clear bits i through j
          in n. EXAMPLE: i = 2, j = 4. Result
          should be 11100011. For simplicity, we'll
          use just 8 bits for the example. */
       
        int allOnes = ~0; // will equal sequence of all ls
       
        // ls before position j, then 0s. left = 11100000
        int left= allOnes << (j + 1);
       
        // l's after position i. right = 00000011
        int right = ((1 << i) - 1);
       
        // All ls, except for 0s between i and j. mask 11100011
        int mask = left | right;
       
        /* Clear bits j through i then put min there */
        // Clear bits j through i.
        int n_cleared = n & mask; 
        // Move m into correct position.
        int m_shifted = m << i;  
          
        // OR them, and we're done!
        return (n_cleared | m_shifted); 
    }
      
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        // in Binary N= 10000000000
        int n = 1024; 
          
        // in Binary M= 10011
        int m = 19;   
          
        int i = 2, j = 6;
       
        System.out.println(updateBits(n,m,i,j));
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand this line:

```
int right = ((1 << i) - 1);
```

Comment: You understand that it's creating a mask? Try looking at the value that's created for a few values of i. Look at it in binary. Look at the values after the shift and before the subtraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1 << i` means you shift the 1 i bits to the left. If i is 2, this would result in the bits being `00000100`. No matter the i, we would always have exactly one 1 in there, followed by i zeros.

Now you take that minus 1 and get `00000011`. If you are familiar with binary you should see that taking a binary number that has exactly one 1 in it minus 1 will always result in a binary number that has some zeros and then ones (regex: `0*1*`).

So in total you get a number that has exactly i bits as 1 at the end.